# Consuming a 3rd Party Android API in Delphi

Tags: java, android, delphi

I am trying to use a Honeywell SDK in Delphi Seattle to control a scanner on an Android device.

Honeywell provided me with a SDK jar called DataCollection.jar. I used the Java2OP utility to create my JNI bridge but am having trouble with it. To be honest I am a novice on this and am not sure where to look or how to implement this. I have searched for similar examples too.

I know I have to create an object of type TJAidmanager to access the barcode reader functions , it is defined as :

```
JAidcManagerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
['{EE70EF80-4CA8-4FE0-B912-6453CA0336CD}']
{class} function _GetBARCODE_DEVICE_CONNECTED: Integer; cdecl;
{class} function _GetBARCODE_DEVICE_DISCONNECTED: Integer; cdecl;
{class} procedure addBarcodeDeviceListener(P1:      JAidcManager_BarcodeDeviceListener); cdecl;
{class} procedure close; cdecl;
{class} procedure create(P1: JContext; P2: JAidcManager_CreatedCallback);    cdecl;
{class} function createBarcodeReader: JBarcodeReader; cdecl; overload;
{class} function createBarcodeReader(P1: JString): JBarcodeReader; cdecl;     overload;
{class} function listBarcodeDevices: JList; cdecl;
{class} function listConnectedBarcodeDevices: JList; cdecl;
{class} procedure removeBarcodeDeviceListener(P1:    JAidcManager_BarcodeDeviceListener); cdecl;
{class} property BARCODE_DEVICE_CONNECTED: Integer read     _GetBARCODE_DEVICE_CONNECTED;
{class} property BARCODE_DEVICE_DISCONNECTED: Integer read   _GetBARCODE_DEVICE_DISCONNECTED;
end;

[JavaSignature('com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager')]
JAidcManager = interface(JObject)
['{98A668C5-9204-4F0C-98B0-A8E1F1124738}']
end;
TJAidcManager = class(TJavaGenericImport<JAidcManagerClass, JAidcManager>)    end;
```

The java sample code looks like this :

```
import com.honeywell.aidc.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AidcManager manager;
private BarcodeReader reader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// create the AidcManager providing a Context and an
// CreatedCallback implementation.
AidcManager.create(this, new AidcManager.CreatedCallback() {

@Override
public void onCreated(AidcManager aidcManager) {
manager = aidcManager;
reader = manager.createBarcodeReader();
}
}
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
// make sure that AidcManager isn't null
if (reader != null) {
// close BarcodeReader to clean up resources.
// once closed, the object can no longer be used.
reader.close();
}
if (manager != null) {
// close AidcManager to disconnect from the scanner service.
// once closed, the object can no longer be used.
manager.close();
}
}
}
```

Now when I try and use this in delphi , I have tried this but get a segmentation fault :

```
var cb : JAidcManager_CreatedCallback;
begin
      TJAidcManager.JavaClass.create(SharedActivity,TJAidcManager_CreatedCallback.Wrap((cb as ILocalObject).getobjectID));
```

The JAidcManager_CreatedCallback is defined as :

```
 JAidcManager_CreatedCallbackClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{E27EF6BB-C642-42B6-98CA-6C270A1AD5D1}']
    {class} procedure onCreated(P1: JAidcManager); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/honeywell/aidc/AidcManager$CreatedCallback')]
  JAidcManager_CreatedCallback = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{E2713D70-1CE6-43AA-9181-7054BD787F1B}']
  end;
  TJAidcManager_CreatedCallback =   class(TJavaGenericImport<JAidcManager_CreatedCallbackClass,   JAidcManager_CreatedCallback>) end;
```

I assume I have to implement an onCreated Event for a variable of type TJAidcManager but I am not sure how to link these all together.

I then tried this :

```
var   cb : JObject;
begin
  cb := TjObject.Create;
  TJAidcManager.JavaClass.create(SharedActivityContext,TJAidcManager_CreatedCallback.Wrap((cb as ILocalObject).getobjectID));
```

I also added this to the JNIBridge Unit in the implementation section :

```
procedure onCreated(P1: JAidcManager); cdecl;//Deprecated
begin
   Form2.manager := P1;
end;
```

When running this, I get a "java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to  service Intent {acct=com.honeywell.decode.DecodeService cmp=com.intermec.datacollectionservice/.DataCollectionService}" error. I tried adding "Bind Remoteviews" to permissions but that didn't help.

If anyone could advise me or point me in the correct direction on how to create the AidcManager in Delphi, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem has been solved. I needed to extend the com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.

The details of the full solution can be found here [Embaradero Forum with link to Source](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205636)

Comment: You've linked your answer to a site that has been down for 2 weeks now. If you update your answer to include the details, I'll remove the downvote :-)