# Integration with Honeywell sink, SecurityException DecodeService without permission

Tags: android, delphi, integration, honeywell

I'm integrating with a reader and to do this use a library of the own collector. This way I create a Java application and integrate this with my mobile application using JNI.

When I open my application on the device, it gives a `securityException` error on the line where I call a method to start a Service from the application itself:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent ();
serviceIntent.setAction ("com.honeywelll.decode.decodeService");
startService (serviceIntent); // In this line of the security exception error
```

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {act = com.honeywell.decode.DecodeService} without permission not exported from uid 10089 EJNIException

NOTE: It works in version 4.1.1 of Java, but in 7.1 this error happens.

Comment: This guy answered his own question regarding the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425929/consuming-a-3rd-party-android-api-in-delphi. Sadly, he has linked his solution to the EMBT forums, which have been down for nearly 2 weeks now.

Comment: I looked at this example that you indicated, right away it stopped working when I migrated to android 7.1, the error keeps happening